# Terms Aggregation based on Distinct Terms per Collection

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents which look like this:

```json
{
  "foo": null,
  "bars": [
    {
      "baz": "BAZ",
      "qux": null,
      "bears": [
        {
          "fruit": "banana"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want buckets of the `fruit` term with counts of how many documents under `bars` contain `bears` with each given `fruit`. For instance, given the following documents:

```json
{
  "foo": null,
  "bars": [
    {
      "baz": "BAZ",
      "qux": null,
      "bears": [
        {
          "fruit": "banana"
        },
        {
          "fruit": "banana"
        },
        {
          "fruit": "apple"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "baz": "BAZ",
      "qux": null,
      "bears": [
        {
          "fruit": "banana"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "foo": null,
  "bars": [
    {
      "baz": "BAZ",
      "qux": null,
      "bears": [
        {
          "fruit": "apple"
        },
        {
          "fruit": "apple"
        },
        {
          "fruit": "orange"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like results that look like this:

```json
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "banana",
    "doc_count": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "apple",
    "doc_count": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "orange",
    "doc_count": 1
  }
]
```

That is, `banana` appears as the descendent of `2` distinct `bars`, `apple` appears as the descendent of `2` distinct `bars`, and `orange` appears as the descendent of `1` distinct `bar`.

Right now I have the following aggregation, which counts the total fruits:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "global": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "bars": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "bars"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "bears": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "bars.bears"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "fruits": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "bars.bears.fruit"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in the following:

```json
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "banana",
    "doc_count": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "apple",
    "doc_count": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "orange",
    "doc_count": 1
  }
]
```

Which is not what I'm looking for. Is it possible to modify this query to count the distinct `bars` which contain each `fruit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to get the results I was looking, although in a slightly different shape:

### Query

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "global": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "bars": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "bars"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "bears": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "bars.bears"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "fruits": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "bars.bears.fruit"
                  },
                  "fruit_to_bears": {
                    "reverse_nested": {}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Results

```json
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "banana",
    "doc_count": 3,
    "fruit_to_bears": {
      "doc_count": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "apple",
    "doc_count": 3,
    "fruit_to_bears": {
      "doc_count": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "orange",
    "doc_count": 1,
    "fruit_to_bears": {
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a working example with index data (taken same as shown in question), mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "bars": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "bears": {
            "properties": {
              "fruit": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "bars": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "bars"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fruits": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "bars.bears.fruit"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "bars": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "fruits": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "apple",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "banana",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "orange",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @knpwrs please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @knpwrs is the search result shown in my answer, different from what you expect to get ? I have considered the sample sample index data as given in the question above, with a different index mapping

Comment: It looks like it works with that index mapping. I may have to go back to the drawing board on what I'm doing here. Thank you!

Comment: my current mapping has bears nested under bars (as you can see from my original query). Is there a way to utilize both mappings or do I have to use one mapping or the other?